# PHP number addition error

Tags: php

```
$score = $_GET['score'];
$ht = $ayarcek['total'];
$total = $ht+$score;
echo $total;

Result: 6.0E-8
```

I want to summarize the numbers `1.000000 + 0` or `1.000000 + 1.000000`, but when I do the collection I get the above result. Where could I have done wrong?

Comment: Your number isn't 'wrong'. That's called scientific notation, and is a way of expressing large (and small) numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It will be helpful for callers

```
$score = $_GET['score'];
$ht = $ayarcek['total'];
$cek = $ht+$score;
$total = sprintf('%.8f', $cek);
```